# To check whether the given system of equations have non zero solution or not

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the system
$$c_1+c_2=0$$

$$c_1 e^k + c_2 e^{-k}=0$$ where $k$ is not zero.

I want to solve this system of equations for $c_1$ & $c_2$ and find the value of k such that k should be non zero. 
My answer comes to be k=$-n\pi$  or $+n\pi$

I also need to find the norm of $\sinh (n\pi x)$, I know that norm of $\sin (n\pi x)$
 is $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$ . Please help me to evaluate the norm of hyperbolic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with $$c_2=-c_1$$ we get
$$c_1(e^k-e^{-k})=0$$ at first we assume that $$c_1=0$$ and so we get $$c_2=0$$
if $$e^k=e^{-k}$$ we get $$e^{2k}=1$$ from here we get $$k=0$$ and $$c_1,c_2$$ are arbitrary real numbers.

Comment: Why can't we use sinh(k) = ($\e^k- e^-k)/2$ ?

Comment: ok you can use it, i think we don't need it

Comment: I need because am trying to find non trivial solution

Comment: you don't need this function, if $k=0$ you have the equation $$c_1+c_2=0$$  with infinity many solutions.